# How to stop Text Overlapping Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, css

If entered message is too long then it overlap with the below text area in chat application

How to solve this issue. 
I have attached images also to make the problem clear.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>MongoChat</title>
    <style>
        #messages{height:300px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">
                MongoChat
                <button id="clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
            </h1>
            <div id="status"></div>
            <div id="chat">
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name...">
                <br>
                <div class="card">
                    <textarea id="messages" class="well card-block">

                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <br>
                <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message..."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
    (function(){
        var element = function(id){
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        // Get Elements
        var status = element('status');
        var messages = element('messages');
        var textarea = element('textarea');
        var username = element('username');
        var clearBtn = element('clear');

        // Set default status
        var statusDefault = status.textContent;

        var setStatus = function(s){
            // Set status
            status.textContent = s;

            if(s !== statusDefault){
                var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                    setStatus(statusDefault);
                }, 4000);
            }
        }

        // Connect to socket.io
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:4000');

        // Check for connection
        if(socket !== undefined){
            console.log('Connected to socket...');

            // Handle Output
            socket.on('output', function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                if(data.length){
                    for(var x = 0;x < data.length;x++){
                        // Build out message div
                        var message = document.createElement('div');
                        message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                        message.textContent = data[x].name+": "+data[x].message;
                        messages.appendChild(message);
                        messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                    }
                }
            });

            // Get Status From Server
            socket.on('status', function(data){
                // get message status
                setStatus((typeof data === 'object')? data.message : data);

                // If status is clear, clear text
                if(data.clear){
                    textarea.value = '';
                }
            });

            // Handle Input
            textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey == false){
                    // Emit to server input
                    socket.emit('input', {
                        name:username.value,
                        message:textarea.value
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })

            // Handle Chat Clear
            clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                socket.emit('clear');
            });

            // Clear Message
            socket.on('cleared', function(){
                messages.textContent = '';
            });
        }

    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

server.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var client = require('socket.io').listen(4000).sockets;

// Connect to mongo
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, db){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('MongoDB connected...');

    // Connect to Socket.io
    client.on('connection', function(socket){
        var chat = db.collection('chats');

        // Create function to send status
        sendStatus = function(s){
            socket.emit('status', s);
        }

        // Get chats from mongo collection
        chat.find().limit(100).sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err, res){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            // Emit the messages
            socket.emit('output', res);
        });

        // Handle input events
        socket.on('input', function(data){
            var name = data.name;
            var message = data.message;

            // Check for name and message
            if(name == '' || message == ''){
                // Send error status
                sendStatus('Please enter a name and message');
            } else {
                // Insert message
                chat.insert({name: name, message: message}, function(){
                    client.emit('output', [data]);

                    // Send status object
                    sendStatus({
                        message: 'Message sent',
                        clear: true
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        // Handle clear
        socket.on('clear', function(data){
            // Remove all chats from collection
            chat.remove({}, function(){
                // Emit cleared
                socket.emit('cleared');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

[First look of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnGT0.jpg)

[Now, I have entered the name and message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOEcQ.jpg)

[Now , message is displayed as i want( working correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2oEn.jpg)

[If i eneter a too long message then i overlaps the below textatarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dROoQ.jpg)

Comment: You really should not be dumping your whole application here. Instead "break down the problem", which in this case is simply your "text area overlaps". Simply include the necessary HTML and CSS in order to present the problem and then simply ask what needs to be done. And we really don't need the pictures either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the height. you specified a fixed `height` for `messages` to be `300px`

Better to change this to add `divs` instead of adding text inside textarea or to make `height` as `auto` but you have to handle scrollbars also in case it exceeds the page height.

```
   <style>
        #messages{height:auto;}
    </style>
```

if you want to keep the height though to `300px` you can add `overflow` too

The `overflow` specifies what should happen if the content overflows an height in your case.

```
   <style>
        #messages{
          height:300px; 
          overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Tnanks @לבני מלכה

Answer (score 1):

**just set** `auto` height to `.card` and `overflow: auto;` for scrolling

```css
.card{
height:auto;
overflow: auto;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">
                MongoChat
                <button id="clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
            </h1>
            <div id="status"></div>
            <div id="chat">
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name...">
                <br>
                <div class="card">
                    <textarea id="messages" class="well card-block">

                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <br>
                <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message..."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,please tell me how to introduce class well of bootstrap, when the the messages are displayed in the screen.